# What construction is "mi si è incastrato"?

Tags: verbs

On the Repubblica.it website today, there is a series of "foto carine", with the headline:

[Oops, mi si è incastrato il cucciolo](http://www.repubblica.it/ambiente/2014/10/19/foto/ops_mi_si_incastrato_il_cucciolo-98491064/1/#1)

I have never seen this type of construction with ***mi*** and ***si*** next to one another. I figure the meaning is something like "My puppy trapped himself." If that is the case, couldn't one say "si è incastrato il mio cucciolo?"

What sort of construction is this? Are there other similar constructions?

Comment: You remember this movie? http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesoro,_mi_si_sono_ristretti_i_ragazzi. 'Mi' means 'to me' and indicates that something has happened to you. 'Mi' is a (particella pronominale) in this case.

Comment: Of course, I appreciate the movie title reference.

Comment: I'll add "mi si è fermato il cuore" to the list of examples. Equivalent to the English "my heart stopped".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a quite usual construct in Italian: often, when in English you would use a possessive adjective (“I wash my face”), in Italian you use a possessive pronoun instead: *mi lavo la faccia*. Here, *lavo la mia faccia* would sound like something a foreigner (or perhaps Google Translate) would say. And where in English you shake someone's hand, in Italian *gli stringi la mano*.

Other common phrases of this kind include *mi fa male il/la [parte del corpo]* = “my [body part] hurts”; or *le tengo i bambini* = “I babysit her children”, and so on.

In your case, it is accidental that the verb is reflexive, so needing a further pronoun *si*. It could as well be, say, *mi è caduto il cucciolo* for “I dropped my puppy”.

Comment: but it's also possible `mi è caduto il tuo cucciolo` that can be translated as `I dropped your puppy`

Comment: Would a decent translation for this construction and register be something like "my puppy got stuck"?

Comment: @gbutters - English is not my first language, but I'd say it sounds similar indeed.

Answer (score 1):

A more strict (literal) translation could be:

```
the puppy trapped himself to me
```

This kind of construction is used to highlight the emotional or personal involvement of someone who isn't not the subject of the sentence.

Few other examples:

Sempre caro mi fu questo ermo colle - Always dear to me was this solitary hill (Leopardi)

Mi si è rotta la lavatrice - The washing machine is broken to me (this is not used, meaning it is wrong, but the literal translation would be written in this way, though you actually need to translate with *my washing machine has broken*.)